# Listing the event handlers for a wxPython window

Tags: event-handling, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wxPython window. How can I check its event handler table? (i.e. which handler is handling each event.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you got your answer from the mailing list, we may as well replicate the answer here:

Robin Dunn wrote:

> There isn't a way to access the event
>   table currently, although I've often
>   thought that it would be a good idea.

Shame.

Comment: Was there any progress on this in the last umm 9 years?